# Why does jQuery wrap the response in an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using an API with an endpoint that returns a JSON object. When calling the API with jQuery, the result is an array containing that object. Why?

From the browser, by typing the URL and looking at the answer, I get

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "foobar"
}
```

When I access the API through Postman, with the same URL, I have the same response.

When I try to access with JS/jQuery, with the following code:

```js
$.get('https://example.com/api/elements/1', data => {
    console.log(data)
})
```

The `console.log` result is this one:

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "foobar"
    }
]
```

Why is there a difference between direct access and jQuery? and, more important, is there a way to retrieve the JSON instead of an array containing a single JSON?

**NOTE:** I have tried in Vanilla JavaScript (using the XMLHttpRequest API) and the result is the same.

Comment: `https://example.com/api/elements/1` doesn't return any JSON for me. Just a page saying it's an example domain.

Comment: Yes, because i'm using an API that's not public, I'm not giving you the real URL. That should not keep anyone from answering the question, though.

Comment: OK, the answer is simple - what you see shouldn't be happening. Unless perhaps the server responds with different data. Or maybe you have a typo in the URL. Or something else which is not in the question.

Comment: how you are getting data from the browser URL. you showed output via `echo` or `print_r` or any other way?

Comment: AS @JarmoT's fiddle shows, jquery does not inherently convert it to an array.  So the answer to your question of "why?" is "it doesn't".  But it does *in your case*, so there must be something different in your case.   It's possible that the server is providing different results based on the request.   Use the network tab in the browser to see the *exact* response from the service, prior to jquery seeing it.

Comment: Tell jquery not to parse the result and then inspect that result, eg `$.ajax({ url:"...", dataType:"text" }).done((result) => console.log(result))`

Comment: You repeat several times that jQuery does it - do you mean that when using, say, `fetch`, or `axios` or whatever, it doesn't happen?

Comment: I edited the question, I hope I answered everyone's question and remark.

Comment: Not really. You've still in no way ruled out the error is in you.

Comment: Rudimentary conversion: `if (data.length === 1) data = data[0]`

Comment: @freedomn-m, I tried to inspect the result using `$.ajax`, it still encapsulates the JSON into an array. Also, thanks for your workaround idea, I thought about that, but I'd rather understand what's going on!

Comment: What about looking at the network response directly in the browser?  Or using `fetch` as suggested above?

Comment: @VLAZ I checked the spelling, it's not that. As for something not in my question, I frankly don't see what.

Comment: @freedomn-m The network response from the browser and from Postman are not encapsulated.

Comment: Was a call to [`jQuery.ajaxSetup`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) made? If so, please share its code. Just need to exclude that a converter is at play here. Otherwise, we really should have a **reproducible** scenario here.

Comment: @trincot: no, I didn't call jQuery.ajaxSetup. And unfortunately, I can't give you a working example as the call is made to an API internal to my company. I'll check with the person who is in charge of the said API. Thanks to everyone involved for trying to solve my problem!

Answer (score 2):

If your API doesn't return an array, jQuery won't parse it into one.

I would recommend checking the API response from a different source (perhaps the browser is doing some formatting to the JSON?).

Example request to dummy API with the jQuery get() function:

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jarmot/9o5r0gy4/

```js
$.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1', data => {
  console.log(data)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```